# Formatting currency values with 2 decimal digits and change negative values to RED

Tags: javascript, formatting

I am attempting to format a currency value to display only 2 decimal digits and also change the output value if negative. Currently, the output is rendering 14 decimal characters and is off by $0.01!

I have a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/3k8L207y/47/) showing the output that depicts these 2 issues I'm having.

The javascript is quite simple! Maybe its simplicity is the cause of the issue.  Here's the script:

```
var accountbalance = 99.99;
var renewalfee = 64.95;
var balanceafterrenewal = (accountbalance - renewalfee);
document.getElementById("remainingBalance").innerHTML = balanceafterrenewal;
```

The HTML code that renders the output is as follows:

```
<div class="remainingbalancelabel">Remaining Balance Rendering Output</div>
   $<span id="remainingBalance"></span>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help in:

1. Formatting the remainingBalance to correctly display the correct value
2. Formatting the remainingBalance to display only 2 decimal characters
3. Color change the remainingBalance to RED when it becomes negative

I'll thank you in advance!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.toFixed` to set to a certain number of decimal places:

```
document.getElementById("remainingBalance").innerHTML = balanceafterrenewal.toFixed(2);
```

Assign to an element's `.style.color` to change its color:

```js
const accountbalance = 99.99;
const renewalfee = 100;
const balanceafterrenewal = (accountbalance - renewalfee);
document.getElementById("remainingBalance").innerHTML = balanceafterrenewal.toFixed(2);
if (balanceafterrenewal < 0) document.getElementById("remainingBalance").style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<span id="remainingBalance"></span>
```

Comment: Thank for your help too! I very much appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I just updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3k8L207y/52/) , simplified things by implementing [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) and changing the code to verify the value if its below zero, to add your class, and also used the `.toFixed(2)` to limit the decimal cases.

Hope it will help!

P.S.: Dorry for overriding your fiddle... I'm kinda new to this thing xD

Comment: Introducing a library and all its new syntax for someone new who's already having issues with the syntax of the base language itself might not be the best idea. IMO it's not great to add unnecessary dependencies for the heck of it